# Laravel Angular Facebook auth

Tags: php, angular, laravel, facebook, oauth

I'm trying to setup a authentication using Facebook provider.

For now I have an Angular 6 app and Laravel 5.6 backend API with Dingo.

What I'm trying to achieve is to make it possible to use facebook account to sing in and make some restrictions however I'm unable do that.

I've tried to use `angularx-social-login` that worked for Angular but I cannot retrieve user by token in my Laravel backend, cause it says that method `userFromTokenAndSecret` does not exist.

```
$providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->userFromTokenAndSecret($request->token, config('facebook.config.secret'));

        $account = SocialFacebookAccount::whereProvider('facebook')
            ->where('provider_id', $providerUser->getId())
            ->first();

        if (!$account->exists) {
            $account = new SocialFacebookAccount([
                'provider_user_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
                'provider' => 'facebook'
            ]);
            $account->save();
        }
```

Comment: Try to use `ng2-ui-auth`. Get `code` from Facebook and send it to the backend. On the backend get user via `Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();`

Comment: How would it get it? Does it consume the request body?

Comment: @AndreyLutskevich just tried to send to API what I retrieve from facebook and resulted in "Client error: `POST https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/oauth/access_token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response…"

Comment: I can't tell you about `ng2-ui-auth` because I don't work with it. Frontend works with this library and sends auth token from facebook to backend (`code`). And on the backend one line `Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();` return full user information.

Comment: So you say I should send an authToken not a user object?

Comment: Yes. From `ng2-ui-auth` to backend you should send only auth token.

Comment: @AndreyLutskevich could you please clarify in which way I should pass it. As far as I understand I should call backend API route using get. Should I pass token via headers or as a payload? Haven't found any clues how Socialite works and what expects the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179586/discussion-between-andrey-lutskevich-and-sergey).